# How to force update NTP date/time on a router?

Tags: openwrt, ntp, router, ntpd

The log of an Asus router with Padavan firmware (might be similar to OpenWrt) showed:

```
Dec  4 16:06:20 NTP Client: Synchronizing time to 0.nl.pool.ntp.org.
Oct 24 18:18:18 NTP Client: System time changed, offset: -1107989283.092767s
Oct 24 18:18:33 pppd[636]: System time change detected.
```

Something is wrong with the NTP update, because the current date is December 4th, not October 24th.

The graphical user interface has no option to update the system date/time using NTP.

How to make NTP to force updating the date/time?

Answer (score 0):

The padavan firmware comes with `ntpd`.

Better also read the ntp.org docs and configure `pool.ntp.org` instead of  `0.nl.pool.ntp.org` as "NTP Server 1:" in your router.

The verbose command to force update the date/time on the router box is:

```
# ntpd -dnq -p pool.ntp.org
ntpd: sending query to 45.159.204.28
ntpd: reply from 45.159.204.28: offset:+1107989283.715956 delay:0.004582 status:0x24 strat:2 refid:0x026a57c0 rootdelay:0.001312 reach:0x01
ntpd: sending query to 45.159.204.28
ntpd: reply from 45.159.204.28: offset:+1107989283.716159 delay:0.004723 status:0x24 strat:2 refid:0x026a57c0 rootdelay:0.001312 reach:0x03
ntpd: setting time to 2023-12-04 18:39:07.420554 (offset +1107989283.716159s)
```